# Writing my own Authentication Backend

Tags: security, web, jwt, backend

I'm developing a web app using Angular2 and Scala. And instead of using any big frameworks like Spring security that does everything for you, I'm thinking using just some libraries and write the system myself.

I plan to use JWT libraries to authenticate requests. Use hashing libraries to encrypt password storage in db. 
What other things do I need to consider to make my system secure? I think I also need to think about CSRF and XSS? What else?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: The owasp top 10, and the several thousand CWEs in the CWE database (https://cwe.mitre.org/). Addressing every CWE will take care of approximately 50% of your security needs.  Wow, it is almost as if security was its own area of study that is as large as any other computer science pursuit. Maybe we can just sum up an entire field of study in a StackOverflow comment.

Comment: The list seems helpful, thanks a lot!